# How to implement upload photo feature in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

My repo: https://github.com/Gtar69/artstore_hw2

I want to implement upload more than 1 photo in certain product.
The basic idea is that administrator enter edit page of the product and can "upload new photos" for certain product.Im struggling in "how to create a photo object in edit page and add this photo object to product. !!! I can not successfully create a photo object in edit page .....

Very Thanks

in view/admin/products/edit.html.erb

```
<h2> 編輯 <%= @product.title %> </h2>

<%= simple_form_for [:admin, @product ] , :html => { :class => "form form-horizontal"  } do |f| %>

  <div class="form-group">

    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <%= f.input :title %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">

    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <%= f.input :description, :as => :text %>
    </div>
  </div>



  <div class="form-group">

    <div class="col-sm-1">
      <%= f.input :quantity %>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="form-group">

    <div class="col-sm-1">
      <%= f.input :price %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- 20140623 upload more than one photo feature added -->
  <div>
    <%= simple_form_for [:admin, @product, @product.photos.build] do |f| %>
      <%= f.input :image , :as => :file %>
      <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.submit "upload new photos", :class => "btn btn-default" , :disable_with => 'Submiting...' %>
      </div>
    <%end%>
  </div>  

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.submit "Submit", :class => "btn btn-default" , :disable_with => 'Submiting...' %>
  </div>

<% end %>
```

in controllers/admin/products_controller.rb

```
  def edit
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    #@photo = @product.photos.build    
    #@product.add_photo_to_product(@photo)
  end
```

in controllers/admin/photos_controller.rb

```
 def create 
    #binding.pry  
    @product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
    @photo = @product.photos.create(photo_params)
    @product.add_photo_to_product(@photo)
    redirect_to admin_products_path
  end  


  private 
    def photo_params
      params.require(:photo).permit(:image)
    end
```

in model/product.rb

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :photos
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :photos

  validates :title , :presence => true
  validates :quantity , :presence => true


  def default_photo
    photos.first
  end

  def add_photo_to_product(photo)
    photos << photo
  end
```

end

in photos.rb

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product

  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
end
```